Someone is somehow able to send spam through my Exchange server
I am running exchange server 15.2 and somehow someone has been sending spam through it.  I have made sure that my 'Default Frontend' receive connector does not allow anonymous connections but somehow that isn't working and I don't know what else to look at.  When I look at the queue, I can still see messages waiting to go out like this (notice the the from address is blank):

Identity: Email2\347358\105106439667717
Subject: Undeliverable: Discover Our Exclusive Luxury Watches. Shop Now For Only $250
Internet Message ID: c9947c19-c8c6-43bf-abf0-80d534a01442@xxxxxxxxxxxx
From Address: <>
Status: Ready
Size (KB): 11
Message Source Name: DSN
Source IP: 255.255.255.255
SCL: -1
Date Received: 12/24/2024 4:15:32 AM
Expiration Time: 12/26/2024 4:15:32 AM
Last Error:
Queue ID: Email2\347358
Recipients:  ukyshcppmspunk@tmc-group.net;2;2;[{LED=};{MSG=};{FQDN=};{IP=};{LRT=}];0;CN=Outbound to Internet,CN=Connections,CN=Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR),CN=Routing Groups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=ChartMeds,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=internal,DC=xxxxxxxxxx,DC=com;0

How can I troubleshoot this?

This seems to be not about programming, but about system administration. Try asking on https://serverfault.com/ instead.
